# PHP average time from an array

Tags: php, time

How do I work out the average time from an array of times.

I have an array that looks like this :

```
('17:29:53','16:00:32')
```

And I wish to achieve the result `16:45:12` using PHP.

Comment: didn't understand why the down vote. It's a relevant and interesting question

Answer (score 17):

```
date('H:i:s', array_sum(array_map('strtotime', $array)) / count($array))
```

Untested solution typed on my phone, should work though.

Comment: what does it return? array?

Comment: @oneofakind var_dump(date('H:i:s', array_sum(array_map('strtotime', $array)) / count($array))); ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
$times = array('17:29:53','16:00:32');

$totaltime = '';
foreach($times as $time){
        $timestamp = strtotime($time);
        $totaltime += $timestamp;
}

$average_time = ($totaltime/count($times));

echo date('H:i:s',$average_time);
```

Answer (score 0):

- convert both using strtotime() function
- add the value
- divide by 2 (or how many items there in your array)
- convert back to normal time format

Answer (score 0):

1. Loop over all Entries and add times, converted to seconds
2. Divide by length of Array and convert back to hh:mm:ss