# php array consist of time values calculate average of it

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, time

I have a php array with time as value
So values like [22:00, 01:00, 01:00, 02:00,:23:30].

I want to find average time but I can't do sum of all and divide.

What I want suppose average of 3 days [22:00, 01:00, 01:00] should be 00:00 (means 00:00 AM) So how can I calculate all. I have such a big size array. So average of 22:00 and 1:00 should be 23:30.

Comment: Why isn't "01:00" 23 hours from 00:00? What makes it only one hour off? Where is the limit? What if the time is 11:00. Is that 13 hours or 11 hours from 00:00?

Comment: he wants average number, so logically 01:00 is 1 hour from 00:00 and 11:00 is 11 hours from 00:00 .. don't think of it as a time, just averaging minutes needs to be rounded to 60 not 100

Comment: Possible replica of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496841/php-average-time-from-an-array

Comment: is each value the time/date a task was done, or is each value the time length the task has taken to complete ?